# Can't start java threads directly after booting BananaPi

Tags: java, linux, node.js, multithreading

At this moment i'm working on a small NodeJs server running on my BananaPi running lubuntu. The server starts as soon as the BananaPi boots and this works; I can reach and interact with it's API interface. Via this API, I can send a command to start a runnable (java) jar. This jar should start a few threads which analyze some images. When I start the server myself from the command line, this works perfectly; once I tell the BananaPi to start the jar (via the API), I can see it running via the process list and the debug log it outputs.

The problem arises when the server is started by the system itself when booting the system. The server just starts normally and behaves the same as when I would start in manually. However, when I give the command to start the jar (via the API) it just exits after it is started. I've put some logging around the starting of the first thread which looks like:

```
log(fh, LOGLEVEL_INFO, "Starting Thread 1");
thread1 = new Thread(new FirstThread());
log(fh, LOGLEVEL_INFO, "Created Thread 1");
thread1.start();
log(fh, LOGLEVEL_INFO, "Started Thread 1");
```

The subsequently generated log only contains:

```
Dec 08, 2014 10:53:29 AM project1.MainThread log
INFO: 2014-12-08 10:53:29 Starting Thread 1
```

It looks like if the creation of a thread fails, but I cant figure out why, especially since all of this works when I start the server myself. Suggestions on how to fix this are welcome :)

Comment: Use a try-catch block and log the exception to find out.

Comment: and if blitz's approach didn't help enough with debugging, just put a sleep or infinite loop at the start of the program and attach a debugger there.

Comment: What kind of exception should I try to catch? I tried to catch a SecurityException but this did not do anything. How can I attach a debugger to an infinite loop and how should this help? My main method just executes until the point where it should start the threads.